# how to using INSERT INTO in c# for access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, command-line, visual-studio-2015

This is mycode
please help me

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|members list.mdb");
        OleDbCommand cmdoledb = new OleDbCommand();
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Members(name,family,age,Juncture scholarships) values('" + t1.Text + "','" + t2.Text + "','" + t3.Text + "','" + t4.Text + "')",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        show();
        t1.Text = string.Empty;
        t2.Text = string.Empty;
        t3.Text = string.Empty;
        t4.Text = string.Empty;

    }
    private void show()
    {
        string d;
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbDataAdapter adap;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|members list.mdb");
        d = "select * from members";
        adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(d, con);
        adap.Fill(ds, "members");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["members"];
    }
```

When I use this code I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Note: Your query is wide open to SQL injection, so you don't even really control the syntax of what you're executing.  Query parameters will be very helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

Use Parameters

When field name contains spaces use brackets

```
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Members(name,family,age,[Juncture scholarships]) values(@name,@family,@age,@Js)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",t1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family",t2.Text);
    ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     ...
```